# Dynamically add element to another dynamically added element

Tags: javascript

I need to dynamically add element, that also been created dynamically. I made two buttons. First must add first element, another - add another element to previously created element. But I got an error, because variable, created in first function, cant reach second function (I got "wrapper is not defined").

What Im doing wrong?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { init(); }, false);

function init() {

    textButton = document.getElementById('textButton');
    pageButton = document.getElementById('pageButton');

    pageButton.addEventListener('click', addPage, false);
    textButton.addEventListener('click', addTextBlock, false);

    function addPage() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
        var wrapper = document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    };

    function addTextBlock() {
        wrapper.innerHTML += '<p class="draggable">Text Here!</p>';
    };

};
```

Comment: The scope of the variable is in the `addPage` function, so you can't access it from `addTextBlock`, you would need to move it outside the function, somewhere in `init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the variable wrapper inside the function `addPage`, so it is private to that function. Declare the variable inside `init()`

Try this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { init(); }, false);

function init() {
    var wrapper;
    textButton = document.getElementById('textButton');
    pageButton = document.getElementById('pageButton');

    pageButton.addEventListener('click', addPage, false);
    textButton.addEventListener('click', addTextBlock, false);

    function addPage() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
        wrapper = document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    };

    function addTextBlock() {
        wrapper.innerHTML += '<p class="draggable">Text Here!</p>';
    };

};
```

Comment: I think it's confusing to initialize `wrapper` to string (i.e., `var wrapper;` is probably better). But, yeah... this should work.

Comment: yeah, its should cast dynamically, though I have updated it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thats it)) So simple... My brain stop working at all as I see. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it happens to me as well, take a break and start fresh :)

Answer (score 1):

Call the function and add it as a parameter

```
 function addPage() {
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'wrapper');
            var wrapper = document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
            addTextBlock(wrapper);
        };

        function addTextBlock(a) {
            a.innerHTML += '<p class="draggable">Text Here!</p>';
        };

    };
```

Just to add some more: wrapper is in local scope and can only be used by the function it is in. So the DIV will append. As you move to your next function you leave the scope of the last function and wrapper is no longer available. You can declare var wrapper as a global but too many globals can get messy. In the method below function addTextBlock takes one parameter (a) You call the function from within the scope of the wrapper and pass wrapper as (a). This is then available for use in addTextBlock

Comment: That is not, what I need, cause "addPage" element created already with "addTextBlock". And I need to add it dynamically too... But thanks anyway...